# html.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

i'm just starting to use asp.net mvc..
since i'm not familiar with it, i just want to ask a question about actionlink html helper..

i have this code in my index.aspx home view..

```
    <%  Dim _news As datatable = ViewData.Model%>
    <%  For count As Integer = 0 To _news.Rows.Count - 1%>
    <%  Dim id As Integer = _news.Rows(count).Item("IDnews")%>
    <%=_news.Rows(count).Item("newsTitle")%>
    <p>
    <%=_news.Rows(count).Item("newsContent")%><br />
    <%=Html.ActionLink("Read More..", "NewsPublic", "Administration", New With {id})%>
    </p>
    <%Next%>
```

if i click the actionlink, i was expecting it will render me to this url:
/Administration/NewsPublic/7 
but rather it gives me this url :
/Home/NewsPublic?Length=14

does actionlink pass id in the same controller only?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Html.ActionLink will use the current controller.  But there are about a dozen overloads of ActionLink(), and there are multiple versions of it that will accept a controller parameter.  Try:

```
Html.ActionLink("Read More...", 
                 "NewsPublic", 
                 "Administration",
                 New With { .id = id },
                 null)
```

Comment: thank you for your response..
um,it gives me this error:
 
Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.

i tried to put . in the "id" but it says identifier expected..

Comment: Yeah sorry... VB initializers are trickier than in C#, I probably didn't get it right.  Try "New With { .id = id }".

Comment: Great.  I'll update my answer text with the corrected initializer.

Answer (score 4):

To render link to **/Administration/NewsPublic/7** you should use

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Read More..", "NewsPublic", "Administration", 
    New With {.id = 7}, Nothing)%>
```

Fifth parameter makes compiler to choose

```
ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, 
    object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

extension method overload instead of

```
ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, 
    object htmlAttributes)
```

And don't forget to add parameter assignment

```
New With {.id = 7}
```

instead of

```
New With {.id}
```